# How to turn many commands into one pipe command in r?

Tags: r, pipe, magrittr

I am very new to the pipe `%>%` operator. Can someone tell me if (and if yes, how) I can turn this into one or maybe two pipe commands?

```
b2m <- b$bdi.2m-b$bdi.pre
b2m %>%
  as.vector(mode = "any")
b2m <- b2m[!is.na(b2m)]
b2m <- b2m^2 
b2m <- sum(b2m)/length(b2m)
b2m
```

When I tried to resume the pipe after the 3rd line I always got errors with the indices.

Edit:

```
> dput(head(b))
structure(list(drug = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", 
"Yes"), class = "factor"), length = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("<6m", ">6m"), class = "factor"), treatment = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("TAU", "BtheB"), class = "factor"), 
    bdi.pre = c(29, 32, 25, 21, 26, 7), bdi.2m = c(2, 16, 20, 
    17, 23, 0), bdi.3m = c(2, 24, NA, 16, NA, 0), bdi.5m = c(NA, 
    17, NA, 10, NA, 0), bdi.8m = c(NA, 20, NA, 9, NA, 0)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `...as.vector() %>% drop_na() %>% mutate(...)`. For further help please share a reproducible example and expected outcome

Comment: could you put a reproducible data example?
Use ```dput(b)``` and post here the result.

Comment: @WilsonSouza I made an edit

Comment: @Sotos `drop_na()` isn't applicable to vectors though. Putting to drop na command before the `as.vector()` command doesn't work either

Comment: You're supposed to give us `dput(head(b))` not the `head` of the `dput()`, because `dput` will print code onto the terminal, and you're supposed to give us that.

Comment: Do all the operations inside the data frame in a pipe and lastly `pull()` the column you need

Comment: @Mossa Ok, I edited it again

Comment: I'm still confused. What is exactly result you are want?

Comment: @WilsonSouza As said in the initial code: `sum(b2m)/length(b2m)`. I do get that result that's not the problem but the code I have doesn't look good and I thought there's probably someway to put this all into a pipe command but I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
b %>% summarise(b2m = sum((bdi.2m - bdi.pre)^2, na.rm = T)/length(bdi.2m))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few approaches. The first uses magrittr `%$%`, the second uses `%>%`, the third uses `|>` from the base of R, the fourth does not use pipes and the fifth uses the [bizarro pipe](https://win-vector.com/2017/01/29/using-the-bizarro-pipe-to-debug-magrittr-pipelines-in-r/) which is just a clever use of base syntax to simulate a pipe.

```
library(magrittr)

b %$% mean((bdi.2m - bdi.pre)^2, na.rm = TRUE)
## [1] 180.6666667

b %>% with(mean((bdi.2m - bdi.pre)^2, na.rm = TRUE))
## [1] 180.6666667

# remaining alternatives use only base R

b |> with(mean((bdi.2m - bdi.pre)^2, na.rm = TRUE))
## [1] 180.6666667

with(b, mean((bdi.2m - bdi.pre)^2, na.rm = TRUE))
## [1] 180.6666667

b ->.; with(., mean((bdi.2m - bdi.pre)^2, na.rm = TRUE))
## [1] 180.6666667
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with pipe. The problem you had come from the fact that the pipe give the result of the previous line as the first argument of the function, and because of that it will not work for something like `b2m[!is.na(b2m)]`, because it is not a function (the function is inside the []). You need to tell R where to pass the result of the previous line and it can be done with a `.`

But it would not work for `sum(b2m)/length(b2m)`, for a different reason: there is two functions so you need to transform it as one function (this can be done by putting this line between `{}`. Or you can separate the operations in two line.

A result of what you want can be:

```
b2m <- b$bdi.2m-b$bdi.pre
b2m %>%
  as.vector(mode = "any") %>%
  .[!is.na(.)] %>%
  .^2 %>%
  {sum(.)/length(.)}
```

This is a complement of what @Wilson Souza wrote, as it can be more readable, especially when you have to use lot of pipes with complicated functions.